# C# I want to know how to .Add () the same image to the Magick ++ MagickImageCollection class

Tags: c#, magick++

Although it is the `///` comment part internal code of the presentation code
I'm inserting the same image using the `.Add ()` method of the `ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection ();` class, but when I insert the second one I get the following exception,
but I insert the same image Need to reload again? I don't want to do that because it takes a lot of processing time.

###### Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Not allowed to add the same image to the collection.'
```

###### Reference site

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/main/docs/ConvertPDF.md

##### Environment

OS: Windows10

IDE: Visual stuido 2022

Language: C#

API: .Net 6.0

Library: Magick ++, Ghostscript

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ImageMagick.MagickImage img = new ImageMagick.MagickImage("input.HEIC");

        ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection images = new ImageMagick.MagickImageCollection();

        images.Add(img);
/////////////////////////////////////
        images.Add(img);
/////////////////////////////////////
        images.Add(img);
        images.Add(img);
        images.Add(img);



        images.Write("output.pdf");

        img.Dispose();
        images.Dispose();

        Console.WriteLine("終了");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the second image like this:

```
var img1 = new ImageMagick.MagickImage(img); ;
```

Then add img1

```
images.Add(img1);
```